# weak references in .net

Tags: .net, weak-references

Can someone give some examples of using weak references in .net projects ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Think about cache with 2 levels. So objects in the 1st level are referenced with normal references and in then 2nd level with weak references. Thus if you want to expiry your object from the 1st level you can put it in the 2nd level.

Next time, when client tries to access this object if you have enough memory object will be promoted from the 2nd level, however if memory is not enough and object was collected you will have to recreate your object. Sometimes it will be recreated or retrieved from expensive store but in some situation you will be able to find it in the 2nd level.

Answer (score 3):

One scenario is where you want an object to have singleton behavior, but you don't want it to stick around forever with a long-lived reference. For example:

```
class ExpensiveSingleton
{
   private static WeakReference _instanceWeakRef;
   private ExpensiveSingleton() { ... your expensive ctor ... }

   public static ExpensiveSingleton Instance
   {
      get
      {
         ExpensiveSingleton reference = null;

         if(_instanceWeakRef != null)
            reference = _instanceWeakRef.Target as ExpensiveSingleton; // Try a cheap access

         if(reference == null)
         {
             reference = new ExpensiveSingleton(...); // Pay the cost
             _instanceWeakRef = new WeakReference(newInstance);
         }

         return reference;       
      }
   }
}
```

(For brevity, this wasn't made thread safe)

This ensures that all strong references you obtain to that object are the same object, and that when all strong refs are gone, the object will eventually be collected.

Comment: Shouldn't `new WeakReference(newInstance)` be `new WeakReference(reference)`

Comment: For what type of object would this be appropriate?  If the object is expensive to create, I would expect that using weak references could result in bad behavior if an application repeatedly requests a reference, does a little something, and then abandons that reference.  The only objects I would expect to be expensive to hold but not to create would be those than embody considerable mutable state, and I would expect that in most cases such state would be expected to remain valid regardless of whether there were any active references.

Answer (score 1):

There is a good example in the msdn page for [WeakReference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.weakreference.aspx), a sample code which implements caching.

Answer (score 1):

Some good articles:

http://www.switchonthecode.com/tutorials/csharp-tutorial-weak-references

http://www.dotnetperls.com/weakreference

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/dotnet/WeakReference.aspx

One of the big wins when using them is for event subscriptions.  Also for object caches.

Answer (score 1):

[An implementation of the mediator pattern](http://marlongrech.wordpress.com/2009/04/16/mediator-v2-for-mvvm-wpf-and-silverlight-applications/)

[ViewModel locator using MEF](http://johnpapa.net/simple-viewmodel-locator-for-mvvm-the-patients-have-left-the-asylum)