# What are some examples of when to use Weak References?

Tags: c#, weak-references

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [When should weak references be used?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1640889/when-should-weak-references-be-used)

Hi,

When is it good practice to use weak references?

Could somebody provide an example?

Comment: Try searching before asking: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5755860/weak-references-in-net

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An example where they could be used is in [implementing a caching container](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/KeepAliveWeakReference.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

[CAB](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff648747.aspx) (and its open source equivalent, [bbv.Common.EventBroker](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/dotnet/EventBroker.aspx)) uses weak references to allow loosely-coupled event subscriptions between forms (or their MVC controllers).

This allows, for instance, form-A to subscribe to an event on form-B, but still allow form-A to be garbage collected if it were closed first.  Normally, if form-A were closed, it would still hang around in memory because the fact that it's subscribed to an event means there's still a reference to it hanging around.

Really, I would argue that most or *all* event should be weak references.

Answer (score 0):

The [MSDN description](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms404247.aspx) is fairly informative and includes a hypothetical example.